# Multiply each tensor with a value from a another tensor

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I have two tensors:

```
import torch
a = torch.randn((2,3,5))
b = torch.tensor([[2.0, 1.0, 2.0],[0.5, 1.0, 1.0]])
```

And I want to multiply the each element in the last dimension in a with the corresponding element in b. That means when a is:

```
tensor([[[ 1, 2, 3, 4,  5],
     [1, 2,  3,  4,  5],
     [1, 2,  3,  4,  5]],
    [[1, 2,  3,  4,  5],
     [1, 2,  3,  4,  5],
     [1, 2,  3,  4,  5]]])
```

the result should be:

```
tensor([[[ 2, 4, 6, 8,  10],
     [1, 2,  3,  4,  5],
     [ 2, 4, 6, 8,  10]],
    [[0.5, 1.0,  1.5,  2.0,  2.5],
     [1, 2,  3,  4,  5],
     [1, 2,  3,  4,  5]]])
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the two tensor [broadcastable](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html), which is based on the concept of [broadcasting in NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Loosely speaking, you want to have a `1` in the tensor's `shape` when the dimensions do not match.

There are a couple of methods:

- reshaping, e.g. `a * b.reshape(b.shape + (1,))`
- slicing with `None` axes, e.g. `a * b[..., None]`
- unsqueezing, e.g. `a * b.unsqueeze(-1)`

While the most flexible is reshaping, slicing is typically the most convenient, yet fairly explicit.

Answer (score 2):

All I need to do, is to add an dimension:

```
a * b.unsqueeze(-1)
```